# How to get full title (instead of shorttitle) in first reference with biblatex authortitle style?

Tags: biblatex

I use the `authortitle` style with `biblatex` and it works perfect. Except that I would like the full title in the first reference instead of the short title. Is this possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,language=english]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{May2008tpt,
    Address = {Edinburgh},
    Author = {May, Todd},
    Date-Added = {2012-09-08 12:59:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-01-02 15:02:18 +0000},
    Isbn = {978-0-7486-3532-0 (hbk.) :},
    Keywords = {Politisk filosofi},
    Publisher = {Edinburgh University Press},
    Shorttitle = {The Political Thought of Jacques Ranci{\`e}re},
    Title = {The Political Thought of Jacques Ranci{\`e}re : Creating Equality},
    Year = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{isbn}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{url}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{Bdsk-Url-1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
A partition of the sensible in the police order covers over the void or supplement that is partly constitutive of it. There is no police order without the participation of the people, those people who are politically invisible, each in her proper place.\footnote{\cite[48]{May2008tpt}}
\end{quote}

But this covering of the constitutive void can be disrupted. This disruption is the political act, disrupting the common sense of an oppressive order. Todd May describes Rancière's thought on the political as an \emph{active equality}.\footnote{\cite[53]{May2008tpt}} This means putting the normal order, the police order, into question by an act of dissensus. This goes against the normal functioning of the police order that puts everything in order and thereby maintains inequalities.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `\ifciteseen` test to the `cite:title` bibmacro and enable the `citetracker` option.

Note: Instead of `\footnote{\cite{<key>}` you may use `\footcite` or `\autocite` (which defaults to `\footcite` in the `authortitle` style).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle,citetracker=true,isbn=false]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \ifciteseen{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    }{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
    }%
  }%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblatextest.bib}
@book{May2008tpt,
    Address = {Edinburgh},
    Author = {May, Todd},
    Date-Added = {2012-09-08 12:59:28 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2013-01-02 15:02:18 +0000},
    Isbn = {978-0-7486-3532-0 (hbk.) :},
    Keywords = {Politisk filosofi},
    Publisher = {Edinburgh University Press},
    Shorttitle = {The Political Thought of Jacques Ranci{\`e}re},
    Title = {The Political Thought of Jacques Ranci{\`e}re : Creating Equality},
    Year = {2008},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblatextest.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text.\autocite[48]{May2008tpt}

Some text.\autocite[53]{May2008tpt}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]